# Unable to Mock user defined classes using powermock in java 11

Tags: java, migration, java-11, powermock, jacoco

I am trying to migrate from JAVA 8 to JAVA 11. The source code is building fine, But I am facing issues with JUnit for some classes.

I am unable to Powermock user defined classes.
For example, I have a project ABC, which have few packages with few classes in them. TransactionDao is one of the class in my project with few static methods.

I am trying the below :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TransactionDao.class })
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "org.w3c.dom.*", "org.apache.log4j.*","org.xml.sax.*", "javax.xml.*", "javax.script.*", "org.apache.http.conn.ssl.*", "com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.*", "javax.net.ssl.*" })

PowerMockito.mockStatic(TransactionDao.class);
PowerMockito.when(TransactionDao.staticfunc1(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(0).thenReturn(1);
```

But I am getting this error.

**[ERROR] initializationError  Time elapsed: 0.01 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name TransactionDao. Reason: bad LDC: 17
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad LDC: 17**

The dependencies used in my pom for junit are :

```
<junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
<mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
<mockito.core.version>3.2.4</mockito.core.version>
<assertj.version>3.15.0</assertj.version>
<easymock.version>4.2</easymock.version>
<powermock.version>2.0.7</powermock.version>
<jacoco.version>0.8.6</jacoco.version>
<cglib.nodep.version>3.3.0</cglib.nodep.version>
<javassist.version>3.27.0-GA</javassist.version>
<equals.verifier.version>3.1.12</equals.verifier.version>
    


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>${easymock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                 <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jacoco -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Hey, did you get a solution for this?